# Restaurant selector problem using only if conditionals

Tags: python

[image]

```
vegetarian = input('Is anyone in your party a vegetarian? ')
vegan = input('Is anyone in your party a vegan? ')
gluten_free = input('Is anyone in your party a gluten-free?')

if vegetarian == 'yes':
    print("Here are your restaurant choices: Main Street Pizza Company,Corner Cafe, The Chef's Kitchen, Mama’s Fine Italian")

elif vegan == 'yes':
    print("Here are your restaurant choices: Corner Cafe, The Chef's Kitchen")

elif gluten_free == 'yes':
    print("Here are your restaurant choices: Main Street Pizza Company,Corner Cafe, The Chef's Kitchen")
```

Hi, I am trying to solve this problem but I can't think about what else to modify. Tried using three if statements but the output is not working. For example, if I input yes for vegetarian, no for vegan and yes for gluten-free: I am getting Mama's Fine Italian (which isn't gluten-free) because it's satisfying the vegetarian condition.

How can I modify this program using only if-else-if statements? We have not covered lists, other data structures, loops or modules yet.

Comment: Use lists. Lists are great. Lists are useful.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq The book expects to not use lists. So I want to see if it's possible to do it without lists. I am sure you can do it with lists or other methods.

Comment: Looks like there's only three criteria to filter by, so you could manually just write 2^3 = 8 if statements.

Comment: So each if statement would have 3 possibilities?

Comment: No, you have 3 input variables that have 2 possibilities each. That's 2 * 2 * 2 = 8 total cases. You can either list them all in 8 separate ifs or you can nest ifs inside ifs inside ifs.